# How to upload client file to server?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I need to create form to upload file from client side to server in **AX 2012 R3** using **X++**.

Can some one give me link / example regarding this issue?

I try to search and find that I can use class `SysFileStoreManager`, but still confused how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find example use of SysFileStoreManager using the [Cross-reference Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa626961.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I find it a bit bloated.

You can do this:

```
static client container getPackedFileClient(FileName _fileNameClient) 
{
    BinData binData = new BinData();
    binData.loadFile(_fileNameClient);
    return binData.getData();
}
```

This is the `SysFileStoreManager.getPackedFileClient` method, but without the `protected` keyword.
To save the file:

```
static server container saveFileToServer(container _packedFile, Filename _filename)
{
    #File
    BinData b = new BinData();
    b.setData(_packedFile);
    new FileIOPermission(_filename, #IO_WRITE).assert();
    b.saveFile(_filename);
}
```

This is `SysFileStoreManager.copyFileToClient_Client` adapted for general use.  You can the call the methods in sequence:

```
saveFileToServer(getPackedFileClient(clienFileName), serverFileName);
```

The file content is transferred from client to server using a container.